# primefaces 4.0 p:graphicImage firefox bug

Tags: firefox, primefaces, graphicimage

Here is my problem with firefox using primefaces 4.0 communication version: p:graphicImage
I have a list of model, whenever I click 1 item, I would like to get 1 image respectively
In xhtml file

```
<p:fieldset id="modelDiagramView" style="width:100%;height:1280px">
    <p:panel id="panel">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{modelBean.modelImage}" style="width: 100%;" cache="false"/>
    </p:panel>
</p:fieldset>
```

in java bean, only session scope and application scope are running well

```
public StreamedContent getModelImage() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            System.out.println("render_response: id=" + modelID);
            // So, we're rendering the HTML. Return a stub StreamedContent so
            // that it will generate right URL.
            // modelImage = new DefaultStreamedContent();
            if (modelID != null)
                getModelImage(modelID);
        } else {
            System.out.println("real reander: id=" + modelID);
            if (modelID != null)
                getModelImage(modelID);
        }
        return modelImage;
    }
```

In chrome, when I click to item in list, the p:graphicImage will render a new image, however in firefox, only the first item's image will be render, if I want to display the next clicked item, I have to refresh browser(F5). Is it primefaces bug, how can I prevent that problem? Please help me

Comment: To display in image using primefaces follow this answer by Balcus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073905/display-database-blob-images-in-pgraphicimage-inside-uirepeat?rq=1

Comment: Hi, Were you able to fix this issue, i am having the same problem, even i have set the cache = false in graphic image. This can be reproduced in both IE and firefox

Comment: Nope, not all all. I have to use 2 controllers, and one with SessionScope to display image.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a "bug" that browsers doesn't refresh a image with ajax if the URL will not be changed. Therefore you should add a random number to the resource url as below example.

xhtml

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.stream}" id="pic" width="200">
   <f:param name="randomNumber" value="#{beanxxx.randomNumber}"/>
</p:graphicImage>
```

beanxxx

```
public String getRandomNumber() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int low = 10;
    int high = 100;
    int result = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;

    return Integer.toString(result);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's much easier to set cache=false on p:graphicImage.