# p:graphicImage not rendered in Internet Explorer 10+

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to display p:graphicImage with dynamic content. My view:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{loginBean.loginImage}" />
```

Backing bean (Spring Bean / Singleton Scope)

```
public StreamedContent getLoginImage() throws IOException
    {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)
        {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }

        String loginImage;

        if (developmentState)
        {
            loginImage = "dev.jpg";

        } else
        {
            loginImage = "prod.jpg";
        }

        final byte[] bytes = ... load bytes
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), "image/jpg");
    }
```

This works fine in Firefox / Chrome. **But it fails in IE 10+** Instead of real image there is empty box rendered

My login page uses:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

Page is rendered. Only image is missing in IE (Firefox / Chrome renders correctly). No errors on server side even with TRACE level enabled.

IE:

```
<img id="j_idt10" alt="" src="/appContext/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;pfdrid=ufpDFHhNpCx9dNk92OfD7uAPP6LjduXzuDwZf73cSco%3D&amp;pfdrt=sc&amp;pfdrid_c=true">
```

Chrome:

```
<img id="j_idt10" src="/appContext/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;pfdrid=ufpDFHhNpCx9dNk92OfD7uAPP6LjduXzuDwZf73cSco%3D&amp;pfdrt=sc&amp;pfdrid_c=true" alt="">
```

Firefox:

```
<img alt="" src="/appContext/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;pfdrid=ufpDFHhNpCx9dNk92OfD7uAPP6LjduXzuDwZf73cSco%3D&amp;pfdrt=sc&amp;pfdrid_c=true" id="j_idt10">
```

IExplore DEV console says:

```
HTTP    GET 200 44,29 KB    16 ms   <img> for image
/appConctext/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&pfdrid=ufpDFHhNpCx9dNk92OfD7uAPP6LjduXzuDwZf73cSco%3D&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=true
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Image is not displayed in IE10+

Comment: Hello @BalusC. I've added request / image path into original post. It is HTTP 200 if looking into IE Console

Comment: Content-Type image/jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

When opening direct link in IExplore it says:
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the comment of BalusC, I added the Content-Type header **"image/jpeg"** in the DefaultStreamedContent part.

```
return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), "image/jpg");
```

Note: "image/jpg" did not work with Internet Explorer

Comment: Please note that in my original post Content-Type header is set. But it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Browsers doesn't refresh a image with ajax if the URL will not be changed. Therefore you should add a random number to the resource url.
Relate with this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294444/1242160)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that worked in my case.

```
 public StreamedContent getLoginImage() throws IOException {
  if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
   return new DefaultStreamedContent();
  }

  String loginImage;

  if (developmentState) {
   loginImage = "dev.jpg";

  } else {
   loginImage = "prod.jpg";
  }

  final byte[] bytes = ...load bytes

  final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

  BufferedImage bufferedImg = ImageIO.read(stream);
  ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {
   ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "png", os);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/jpg");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing content type from `image/jpg` to `image/jpeg` solved the problem with IE 11.