# Update Primefaces ContentFlow after loaded with lot of images

Tags: ajax, primefaces, contentflow

I have a contentFlow that is updated after change a selectOneMenu

```
< p:selectOneMenu value="#{movil.marca}">
    < p:ajax event="change" listener="#{dropdownView.onMarcaChange()}" update="contentFlow"/>
    < f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs['selectmarca']}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    < f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.marcas}" />
< /p:selectOneMenu>


< p:contentFlow id="contentFlow" value="#{dropdownView.movilescontentflow}" var="movil">
    < p:graphicImage url="#{movil.foto}" styleClass="content" onclick="clickFlow(this, event)"/>
< /p:contentFlow>
```

The problem is that when the contentFlow is updated it has to load a lot of image and the element is rendered before all the images are downloaded.

If I use a galleria instead a contentFow it works OK, yo can see how the images are loaded into the galleria as they are downloaded.

If I refreshed the page (f5) the contentFlow is rendered once all the images are downloadeed and it is rendered OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Primefaces graphicImage rendering is different and that is why it is not working in contentFlow. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073905/display-database-blob-images-in-pgraphicimage-inside-uirepeat/10161878?s=1|0.0000#10161878 If you have to use contentFlow i have an ugly fix: add oncomplete="location.reload();" on your <p:ajax>.

Comment: I edited the post and describe how it is working with a galleria, What is the difference between the load of contentFlow and Galleria? Why with a Galleria I get the expected behaviour?