# Primefaces, p:imageCropper could not display image after upload

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My admin dashboard is built on spring with JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 5.3.

I am developing form for creating new entities, which should work as follows:

1. User fill in all input fields and upload image (using `<p:fileUpload`).
2. Then, the `<p:imageCropper` should be refreshed and displayed uploaded image to be cropped.
3. User cropped image, and press submit button to create new entity and store image on the disk.

Now, I stuck on the 2 step. Uploaded image is not displayed by `<p:imageCropper`.

I have doubts if it's possible to get image to the `<p:imageCropper` image attribute from the StreamedContent obj from the managed bean, like for [`<p:graphicImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073905/problems-displaying-database-blob-image-in-primefaces-graphicimage/10161878#10161878)?

So, please let me know how it could be solved?

Here is my form:

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="createForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:separator />
                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Create card:" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Fill in Name:" for="cardName" />
                    <p:inputText id="cardName" value="#{cardController.name}"
                        required="false" requiredMessage="Please, enter new card Name" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Fill in Description:" for="cardDescription" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="cardDescription" rows="3" cols="33"
                        value="#{cardController.description}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Upload image:" for="cardImage" />
                    <p:fileUpload id="cardImage"
                        fileUploadListener="#{cardController.handleFileUpload}"
                        auto="false"
                        mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages cropped uploaded"
                        sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3"
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="change size of the image:" for="cropped" />
                    <p:imageCropper id="cropped" value="#{cropperView.croppedImage}" image="#{cardController.image}" initialCoords="225,75,300,125"/>
                    <p:graphicImage id = "uploaded" value="#{cardController.image}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Create"
                        action="#{categoryController.create()}"
                        update=" createForm" />
                    <p:message for="cardName" />


                </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class CardController {

    private CroppedImage croppedImage;
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("!!! inside file upload");
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        uploadedFile = event.getFile();

    }

    public StreamedContent getImage() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            // So, we're rendering the HTML. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }
        else {
            // So, browser is requesting the image. Return a real StreamedContent with the image bytes.
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedFile.getContents()));
        }
    }

    public void create() {
        // shoul be logic for creating new entities
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public CroppedImage getCroppedImage() {
        return croppedImage;
    }

    public void setCroppedImage(CroppedImage croppedImage) {
        this.croppedImage = croppedImage;
    }

    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }

}
```

Comment: @BalusC: Hi, thanks for fast response. When I use custom ViewScope, then the `<p:graficImage` not woking, therefore I change it to session scope, just for test purposes. I'd like to live controller in ViewSope. After a hard refresh, the image is still visible in browser.

Comment: @BalusC: Should `<p:imageCropper ` get image for `value` attribute in two separate HTTP requests? Or it use some different mechanism then `<p:graficImage` ?

Comment: @BalusC: Update previous comment: Should <p:imageCropper get image for **image** attribute in two separate HTTP requests? Or it use some different mechanism then <p:graficImage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have solved my issue this way:

1. After image was uploaded, store it in temp directory on disk.
2. Update component where `<p:imageCropper` is located. The `image` attribute of `<p:imageCropper` should equals to the path created above(e.g: value="http://localhost:8080/temp/#{bean.imageName}"). Note, that directory on the disk, should be visible to your web container ( My app is build on Spring boot, therefore it uses embedded Tomcat. So, I have installed additional apache server and save my images there).
3. Crop the image and store it on the disk.

Here is some code:

```
<p:fileUpload id="cardImage"
                    fileUploadListener="#{cardController.handleFileUpload}"
                    auto="true" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                    update="messages cropped cropButton" sizeLimit="5000000"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" id="cropped">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Crop image:" for="cropper"
                        rendered="#{not empty cardController.imageFilePath}" />
                    <p:imageCropper id="cropper"
                        rendered="#{not empty cardController.imageFilePath}"
                        value="#{cardController.image}"
                        image="#{cardController.hostName}/#{cardController.imageFilePath}"
                        aspectRatio="1.0" initialCoords="225,75,300,125" minSize="210,210" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Cropped image:" for="image"
                        rendered="#{not empty cardController.croppedImageFileName}" />
                    <p:graphicImage id="image"
                        rendered="#{not empty cardController.croppedImageFileName}"
                        value="#{cardController.hostName}/images/#{cardController.categoryId}/#{cardController.levelId}/#{cardController.croppedImageFileName}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="cropButton"
                        rendered="#{not empty cardController.uploadedFile}" value="Crop"
                        action="#{cardController.crop()}" update="messages cropped create"
                        icon="ui-icon-scissors" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Create" id="create"
                        rendered="#{not empty cardController.croppedImageFileName}"
                        action="#{cardController.create()}"
                        update=":cardForm:table createForm" />
                    <p:message for="cardName" />
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Controller:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
        uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        File directory = new File(rootPath + TEMP_DIRECTORY);
        directory.mkdirs();
        String filename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile.getFileName());
        Path file = Files.createTempFile(directory.toPath(), filename + "-", "." + extension);
        Files.copy(uploadedFile.getInputstream(), file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        imageFilePath = TEMP_DIRECTORY + "/" + file.getFileName().toString();
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", imageFilePath + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
public void crop() throws IOException {
        if (image == null) {
            return;
        }
        String imageName = URLUtils.slugify(StringUtils.transliterateRu2En(name));
        String croppedImagePath = IMAGES_ROOT_DIRECTORY + "/" + categoryId + "/" + levelId;
        File directory = new File(rootPath + croppedImagePath);
        directory.mkdirs();

        String filename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(imageName);
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(image.getOriginalFilename());
        Path file = Files.createTempFile(directory.toPath(), filename + "-", "." + extension);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getBytes());
        Files.copy(is, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        croppedImageFileName = file.getFileName().toString();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success", "Cropping finished."));
    }
```