# Insert Image primefaces on form with link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a entity attribute String for input a link_logo in my form , i want just to know what can i write on the  view for input the logo.

The Attribute on entity (agency):

```
 @Column(name = "Logo")
     private String link_logo;
```

My save method it worked and the bean too. I searched in the showcase but no result.

there is my view code now :

```
 <div class="ui-sm-12 ui-md-2 ui-lg-1">
                           <p:outputLabel value="Upload image:" for="img" />
                        </div>
                          <div class="ui-sm-12 ui-md-4 ui-lg-5" >
                        <p:graphicImage id="img" value="#{agenceFormBean.agence.link_logo}" style="width:100%" />

                         </div>
```

any solutions please ?

Comment: Confusing. Are you concretely asking how to upload a file or are you asking how to generate a HTML <img> element and/or how to generate a HTML <a> element?

Comment: thank you for answer ,I just precised that I use SpringBoot, i just know how to insert a image on form in prmefaces. I said i have a StringAtrribut for this image !

Comment: So your `private String link_logo` property contains an URL (e.g. `https://example.com/foo/bar.png`) and you ask how to display this in the browser using JSF?

Comment: no @Selaron , i have a image on my desktop,and i want to insert it on a from view(primefaces) with the another field ,this image will be setting on a String attribut(link_logo), thank you !

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073905/display-database-blob-images-in-pgraphicimage-inside-uirepeat or even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent/12452144#12452144

Comment: You need to tell which value exactly the `link_logo` variable contains. You also need to tell where exactly the physical image file is stored. Then we can help you. Ultimately, the generated HTML `<img>` element must have a `src` attribute which represents an URL to the image. That's how images work in basic HTML. If you already can't use a `<img src="...">` then you also can't do much with JSF because this is in the context of this problem merely a HTML code generator.

Comment: thank you @BalusC for answer, link-logo its a String Value on the entity class,and the image is stocked on a folder in my desktop . now i want just insert it in the database .
thank you so much

Comment: You did not understand me. I asked for the **exact** value and **exact** location. You still haven't answered this. Now still nobody can explain you how to do the math. I'll can only give you an advice: take a step back and learn how basic HTML `<img>` works. Once you understand it, it will be much easier to understand how to use JSF to generate a HTML `<img>` element.

Comment: thank you so much @BalusC.
now i upload the image correctly in a folder :

  public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
         ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
         File result = new File(extContext.getRealPath("//WEB-INF//images//"+event.getFile().getFileName()));

my problem now its i have another method save() in my Form bean,and i want to upload this image with the form id .

Comment: Wow. You actually wanted to ask how to upload an image. You didn't want to ask how to display an image.

Comment: yeah sorry if i wasn't clear before !

Comment: thank you @BalusC, but i want to upload an image with form , i mean when i click on save  the image will be saved on the id of this form object

Answer (score 0):

You can use this the show image with url

```
<p:graphicImage id="img" value="#{yourView.link_logo}" style="width:100%" />
```

Comment: thank @Black for answer,did you mean : value="#{yourBean.link_logo}" ?
i posted my recent view code on reply just now

Comment: Yes, I think your code looks true. There is any problem?

Comment: Your string should be start with http://

Comment: yes, my problem is how to insert a image to set in a String Attribut on primefaces?the GraphicImage is just for display on vien i think.