# JSF graphicImage

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat, graphicimage

I have to do a list of images. I use ui:repeat to do this, but it doesn't work and I can't see the images:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{mybean.album.images}" var="image">  
   <p:graphicImage value="#{image.image}" width="200px" height="180px"/> 
</ui:repeat>
```

But if I use this, it work:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{mybean.album.images[0].image}" width="200px" height="180px"/>
```

I see the first image. 
How can i solve it ?

Comment: what kind of list is `mybean.album.images`?

Comment: It's a List<Image> and Image has getter for image property.

Comment: getImage return a StreamedContent image.

Comment: Is `Image` a custom class? Can you post it (or pastebin)?

Comment: check the following post it will help you.

[link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944673/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-defaultstreamedcontent-in-an-uirepeat)

[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014362/unable-to-display-image-in-pgraphicimage)

Comment: it looks like @BalusC has already answered this (and twice).