# Graphic Image not showing in Datagrid PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have problem regarding displaying image in datagrid column. When Datagrid loads it shows the image correctly but whenever I click on second page or refresh the first page, images are gone. I noticed in the console, clicking on second page or refresh the page made the param value null. That's why Image are not showing. I am using sessionscoped. Below is my code:

```
 public StreamedContent getStreamedImageById() {
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

if (context.getRenderResponse()) {
    // So, we're rendering the view. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.

    System.out.println("check");
    return new DefaultStreamedContent();
}
else {
    // So, browser is requesting the image. Get ID value from actual request param.
    String firstName = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("firstName");
    System.out.println("Name:"+firstName);
    System.out.println("Image::"+images.get(firstName));

    return images.get(firstName);

}
```

In search method I just take all the images in a hash map.

```
      while(itr.hasNext()){

                com.sysvana.request.UserBean us=itr.next();

            images.put(us.getFirstName(), stringToStreamedContent(us.getJpegPhoto()));
            }
```

Here is my xhtml::

```
         <p:graphicImage value="#{userManagementActionBean.streamedImageById}" height="40" width="50" style="align:center"  >

                <f:param id="firstName" name="firstName" value="#{user.firstName}" />
              </p:graphicImage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

```
return images.get(firstName);
```

is not right. You should **create** the streamed content right there and not return one which is already created before in a previous HTTP request. The whole point is that you should not create it in a previous HTTP request, but directly in the very same HTTP request as the `getStreamedImageById()` method is invoked.

Fix it like follows (assuming that `userBean.getJpegPhoto()` returns `byte[]`)

```
UserBean userBean = userService.findByFirstName(firstName);
return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(userBean.getJpegPhoto()));
```

#### See also:

- [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/12452144#12452144)
- [How to use <p:graphicImage> with DefaultStreamedContent in an ui:repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944673/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-defaultstreamedcontent-in-an-uirepeat/10951201#10951201)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the method name `stringToStreamedContent()` suggests a major problem. An image is absolutely not to be represented as a `String`, but as `byte[]`. When treating an image as a `String`, you would likely end up in corrupt images due to the information being lost by character encoding issues. You should obtain the image from the DB as `byte[]` or `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But my problem is related to fetching the param value. Whenever I click on datagrid pagination or refresh the page, I mean calling the getStreamedImageById() method second time, param gets null.

Comment: Ok.. Now I successfully display the image in grid. Thanks for your help.