# Displaying a list of p:graphicImage using ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

page:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{testController.photos}" var="item">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{item}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

bean:

```
private TestEntity current;

public List getPhotos() {
    StreamedContent image;
    Collection rawPhotoCollection = current.getPhotoCollection();

    List<StreamedContent> imageList = new ArrayList<StreamedContent>(rawPhotoCollection);
    List<Photo> photoList = new ArrayList<Photo>(rawPhotoCollection);

    for (int i = 0; i < photoList.size(); i++) {
        byte[] data = photoList.get(i).getImage();
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");
        imageList.set(i, image);
    }

    return imageList;
}
```

TestEntity has a collection of Photo Entity.
I casted the Photo Collection into an Array List of Photos.
Photo has a column Image declared as BLOB.
Created a Loop to retrieve each Image so i can convert it to a StreamedContent.
Inserted each StreamedContent into imageList (a List of StreamedContent)
returned the imageList and displayed it as p:graphicImage.

the problem is, the page gives me an icon of a broken image. it does not display the image. I am pretty sure that it has an image coz if i wont use ui:repeat and just display the selected Photo Entity using p:graphicImage, it displays the correct image.

something like:

page:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{testController.firstImage}"/>
```

bean:

```
public StreamedContent getFirstImage() {
    Collection rawPhotoCollection = current.getPhotoCollection();
    List<Photo> photoList = new ArrayList<Photo>(rawPhotoCollection);
    byte[] data = photoList.get(0).getImage();
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    StreamedContent image = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");
    return image;
}
```

the above code works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use <p:graphicImage> with DefaultStreamedContent in an ui:repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944673/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-defaultstreamedcontent-in-an-uirepeat)

Comment: @BalusC hi, in reference of the link above, im confuse on this `private List<Long> imageIds; // +getter` on my database the images are saved as blob, how can i give them unique image identifiers?

Comment: Just use whatever you already use to select a single and specific image from the DB. E.g. the PK column?

Comment: ok thanks, now i have the list of IDs. now im confuse on what is ImageService of `Image image = service.find(Long.valueOf(id));`