# Retrieve blob images from the database and printing it as image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

this is my `ui:repeat` inside the javascript

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{testController.allItems}" var="item">
        image = '<p:graphicImage width='50px' value='#{imageStreamer.image}' ><f:param name='id' value='#{item.id}' /></p:graphicImage>';
        point = new google.maps.LatLng(#{item.latitude},#{item.longitude});
        createMarker(point, '#{item.name}', '#{item.address}', image);
 </ui:repeat>
```

`testController.allItems` returns a list of entities with values and an image that is saved as `blob`, i'm trying to do a store locator using google maps. `createMarker` adds marker to the map.

i am using `BalusC's` way to print `p:graphicImage` in a `ui:repeat`. reference: [How to use <p:graphicImage> with DefaultStreamedContent in an ui:repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944673/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-defaultstreamedcontent-in-an-uirepeat)

this is my `createMarker`

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address, image) {   
    var html = image+'<br/> <b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

everything works fine. there are markers on my map and when clicking the marker it displays me the image and the name + address. but the problem is, when i click the marker again, the image disappears and the image displays a broken link.

is there another way to retrieve blob images from the database and printing it as image using javascript rather than using `p:graphicImage`?

Comment: Are you using Primefaces ?

Comment: yes i am using primefaces. `p:graphicImage` is one

Comment: And you are using Gmap component of Primefaces ?

Comment: When you have error, you should use Inspect element function of browser to get the error.

Comment: i don't have any error. its just that the 2nd time i click on the marker displays the image as a broken link

Comment: I think your problem come from "click event(on marker)", did you try to debug in `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()`, like `alert(html);` ?

Comment: the data of html on the 1st and 2nd click are the same.

Comment: The data are same..., i really want to debug your problem, see you again in last night.