# primefaces dynamic images from multiple upload

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, galleria

I have a simple form with a fileupload. the file upload and backing bean works perfect but i want to display uploaded images after upload. I've used ui:repeat **but only the first image repeats for all uploads**!
I used multiple p:graphicImage instead of ui:repeat and result is absolutely correct. but i have to use ui:repeat or p:galleria.

here is ui:repeat usage with wrong result

```
<ui:repeat value="#{applicationImagesBean.screenidx}" var="idx">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{applicationImagesBean.getScreen(idx)}" height="320"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

and here is multiple p:graphicImage which is correct but it's not what i want

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{applicationImagesBean.getScreen(0)}" height="320"/>
<p:graphicImage value="#{applicationImagesBean.getScreen(1)}" height="320"/>
<p:graphicImage value="#{applicationImagesBean.getScreen(2)}" height="320"/>
```

note that screenidx is a simple list contains 0,1,2,3, ... as integers

```
public StreamedContent getScreen(Integer idx) {
    try {
        File file = screenFiles.get(idx);
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(file), null, "" + idx.intValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

in both samples I had a breakpoint on getSceen and idx has been sent correctly to getScreen but the result was different.

I tired a `cache = false` and a `timestamp` parameter but no result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display image from database with p:graphicImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage) and [How to use `<p:graphicImage>` with DefaultStreamedContent in an ui:repeat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944673/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-defaultstreamedcontent-in-an-uirepeat/10951201#10951201). In a nutshell: use `<f:param>` instead.

Comment: i tried f:param too, the result is same and my problem still there

Comment: Did you also read the linked answers from top to bottom and **understand** the concrete problem? Your bean and method also needs to be changed and such.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. when we use el2 and pass idx as a method parameter, jsf use that in render time (PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE). and in second call of the method, parameter is always idx = 0 (i dont know why!).

Comment: That part was already explained in the linked answers. Why exactly didn't you bother to *read* them?