# WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file dynamiccontent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dynamic-content, graphicimage

I get the following warning under eclipse :

```
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file dynamiccontent. To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml
```

This error is caused when I post a picture

below primefaces composant :

```
<p:graphicImage  value="#{bean.image}"/>
```

Java Bean :

```
private StreamedContent image;

// Getter
public StreamedContent getImage() {
    try {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("",
                        createDataset(), true, true, false);

        PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) jfreechart.getPlot();

        File chartFile = new File("dynamichart");
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(chartFile, jfreechart, 375, 300);
        chartImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(
                        chartFile), "image/png");
        return chartImage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }
}

// generate data for image
public static PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataset.setValue("A",10);
    dataset.setValue("B", 11);
    dataset.setValue("C", 80);
    dataset.setValue("D", 12);
    return dataset;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your filename must be `dynamichart.png` (note the suffix of the filename).

Comment: Share with us more of your xhtml code. Where you are using this graphic image component?

Comment: +1 I get this message as well.  I am interested in why, but then I never researched this because it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: @maple_shaft, never researched it? [This is all you man](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9533162/1530938) :). [This](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3546) from the primefaces bug tracker

Comment: @kolossus HAHAHAA!!  That's funny!  C'mon man, how am I supposed to remember what I did a year ago? ;-)

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı I have not used more than the indicated component.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I still have the same WARNING with 'dynamichart.png' :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one solution.

by using the latest version of primefaces (3.5).

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>3.5</version>  
</dependency>
```

but there will unpleasant changes in IHM

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the following to your web.xml file

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jsp <!--{or the extension of file}--></extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 7):

I just want to share my experience with a similar problem, I use `maven`, `netbeans` and `payara`. Once I had this warning:

> WARNING No mime type could be found for file fontawesome-webfont.woff is logged

The solution to remove this warning was adding the following code to the `web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**Note:** I had the same warning with different files, those files had different extensions (`woff, eot, woff2 and ttf`). The solution to this was to replace `woff` in `<extension>` with one of the extensions previously mentioned.

I hope that my answer will help someone someday.

PS : I found the solution in this [page](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13420).

Answer (score 1):

I had the JSF1091 warning for `http://example.org`  and `javascript:;` as well, with Icefaces instead of Primefaces.

Changing

```
<ice:outputLink onclick="..." value="javascript:;">...</ice:outputLink>
```

to

```
<ice:outputLink onclick="..." value="/some/url">...</ice:outputLink>
```

silenced the warning about `javascript:;`.

Changing

```
<ice:outputLink value="http://example.org"/>
```

to

```
<a href="http://example.org"/>
```

fixed it for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Although I post this answer after a while probably it will be useful for other developers who face this problem.

To avoid that annoying warning from above add the following code into your web.xml :

```
<mime-mapping>
<extension>png</extension>
<mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

For more details please check:

http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/weblogic-10340-oepe-maven-primefaces.html

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot 2:

```
@Configuration
public class JsfConfigurationMimeMapper implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("xsd", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        mappings.add("otf", "font/opentype");
        mappings.add("ico", "image/x-icon");
        mappings.add("svg", "image/svg+xml");
        mappings.add("eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject");
        mappings.add("ttf", "application/x-font-ttf");
        mappings.add("woff", "application/x-font-woff");
        mappings.add("woff2", "application/x-font-woff2");
        mappings.add("xhtml", "application/xml");
        factory.setMimeMappings(mappings);

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

if you have spring you can also have (I added most of fa-Icons):

```
@Configuration
public class JsfConfigurationMimeMapper implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

     @Override
     public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("xsd", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        mappings.add("otf", "font/opentype");
        mappings.add("ico", "image/x-icon");
        mappings.add("svg", "image/svg+xml");
        mappings.add("eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject");
        mappings.add("ttf", "application/x-font-ttf");
        mappings.add("woff", "application/x-font-woff");
        mappings.add("woff2", "application/x-font-woff2");
        mappings.add("xhtml", "application/xml");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is when you use Spring **AND** an embedded container, so you are most likely running SpringBoot?

Comment: yeah exactly, this is also a solution if you are using SpringBoot. an alternative for those who are not using web.xml. basically you are adding your maps on MimeMappings.