# JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm working with a web application with the following

- jsf 2.3.3
- Prime Faces 6.2
- Omnifaces 3.0
- Payara 4.1, build 181

The problem is that, in all the ajax calls (with p:ajax for example) in the Payara console I see the following

**JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file *null***

My difficulty is that I never saw an error like this in which the word after "file" is "null". Someone have experienced the same issue?

How can I solve the problem?
Thank you

Comment: See if one of this links can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587417/warning-jsf1091-no-mime-type-could-be-found-for-file-qcformdean-jsp-but-wait?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984154/warning-jsf1091-no-mime-type-could-be-found-for-file-dynamiccontent/20163409?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: In all that cases, the message was referred to a specific resource. Unfortunately in my case there're no information about the resource. Basically the problem is the "null" resource.

Comment: Debug, set breakpoints...

Comment: I get the same warning using Wildfly 16 and javax:javaee-api:8.0. I bet on Mojarra...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are loading any Javascript files via outputScript, if that is the case try removing the target attribute from those tags.