# Previous barcode is displayed when attempting to display dynamically generated barcodes

Tags: jsf, primefaces, barbecue

When I generate barcode dynamically, it always prints the previous input, not the latest code. When I refresh the page with refresh button on the browser, the correct barcode is displayed. But If I refresh the page with a JSF commandbutton, still the previous result. Where have I gone wrong ?

JSF 2.1
Primefaces 4.0
Barbecue 1.5 beta
Chrome/Firefox Latest Updates

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{barcodeController.createBarcodeByCode(patientController.current.code)}" 
                style="max-width: 7.5cm; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;" >
</p:graphicImage>
```

This is from the JSF controller with request scope.

```
public StreamedContent createBarcodeByCode(String code) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // So, we're rendering the view. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    } else {
        barcode = null;
        System.out.println("code = " + code);
        if (code == null || code.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        File barcodeFile = new File(code);
        try {
            BarcodeImageHandler.saveJPEG(BarcodeFactory.createCode128C(code), barcodeFile);
            barcode = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(barcodeFile), "image/jpeg");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ex = " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return barcode;
    }
}
```

References:

[1. Dynamic StreamContent Answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304967/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-streamedcontent-within-pdatatable)

[2. Dynamic Barcode with Primefaces](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/dynamic-images-with-jsf/)

Answer (score 4):

Set `cache="false"` on the `p:graphicImage`.