# Image not displaying properly with p:graphicImage

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces upload to store image as array of byte in mysqldb. Now I want to retrieve these images from Db and display it in a datatable. When my datatable is populated , some images are displayed and some are not. I think JSF is having issue while rendering the image. 
Here is my code:

My datatable:

```
     <p:dataTable id="dta" value="#{CarComponent.carList}" var="current" rows="100" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
        <p:column>
            <p:graphicImage value="#{current.tempPhoto}"/>
        </p:column>
     </p:datatable>
```

Entity class:

```
      Table(catalog = "cardb", name = "car")
      public class Car implements Serializable {

      //some fields....

      @Column(name = "CAR_ID", length = 50, nullable = false)
      @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @Id
      @XmlElement
      String carId;

      @Column(name = "CAR_IMG", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
      @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @Lob
      @XmlElement
      byte[] carImg;

      @Transient
      StreamedContent carPicture;

      //getters and setters
      }
```

CarComponentImpl.Java

```
  @Scope("session")
  @Component("CarComponent")
  public class CarComponentImpl implements CarComponent{

         //some declarations
         private List<Car> carList;

         public initialiseCar(){
              carList = carDao.findAllCars();

              for(Car cars: carList){
              car.setCarPicture(new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(car.getCarImg()), car.getCarId().toString()+"image/png"));
              }
      }

     //Getter and setters of car list
}
```

Please help if you have a solution. The image is stored in DB but it does not display all the time.

Comment: 1. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304967/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-streamedcontent-within-pdatatable 2. Add new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(car.getCarImg()), car.getCarId().toString()+"image/png") in getCarPicture instead of Initialise method

Comment: If the upload succeeds, why did you use the file-upload tag?

Comment: And according to your title (the summary of the issue), it works if you upload in another way then PrimeFaces?

Comment: @kukeltje I cant get your point. If i dont use file-upload, how will i upload the images?

Comment: @Mahendran Where should i include this? My getter and setter is in entity class.

Comment: Plain jsf upload, directly store it in the db via a java application with a main method etc… .

Comment: @Alina in the getter of entity

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar  can i call my service or dao in my entity class? If i need to pass a parameter in my query , how do i do this?

Comment: @Alina ask a new question for that